# How do you create a billboard in OpenGL ES?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

Does anyone know how to create a billboard in OpenGL ES for the iPhone?  I been looking for a tutorial but they seem non existent.  I know how to create normal objects etc and apply a texture to it, but am looking to have walls with photos on them in my game.

Update:
So what I am looking for is the best way to put a photo quality image that could be any size in to 3D world.  I believe textures have to be certain sizes etc (128 * 128, 256 * 256 or 128 * 256 (are they square numbers?).  I have seen examples of this in PhotoCastle3D and 3D Gallery)

2nd Part to this would be displaying this as a billboard that always face forward, good example would be for trees or bushes in a game.  Thank you all for some good info, will go investigating.

Comment: When you say that you are looking to have photos on walls, are you just asking how to texture a rectangle?  Or are you looking for a traditional OpenGL billboard that always faces toward the viewer?

Comment: If the latter, this question might provide some guidance: [Getting sprites to face the camera properly in OpenGLES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512326/getting-sprites-to-face-the-camera-properly-in-opengles)

Comment: Brad you fixed it again for again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the billboard is not a component of the texture on the wall, but rather a separate object in the 3d view that is placed very closely to the wall, check out polygon offset.  It's should be available in opengl-es. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPolygonOffset.xml

Basically its a quick way to resolve z-fighting between polygons, if their vertices both try to occupy the same place in the z buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on this, but if I understand you correctly I need to know how to do the posted question before I need to worry about z fighting?

Comment: Correct, I was mistaken about your question. Looks like Brad had the right link that would be the most help to you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial that may be helpful:

http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-441D327D-D737-42A2-BCEA-FE89FBCA2F35/OpenGLEx/Billboard/doc/index.html

Comment: This is a nokia example which could be good but what versions of OpenGL ES does it support?